# robocopy monitor source, save versions

Tags: robocopy

Is it possible to use the `robocopy` command with the monitor source switch to copy files with a new file name when they change?

I use the command below but would like to explore leave it running for several hours and capturing changes. In its current state the command overwrites changes in the destination folder.

`report.txt` can have several changes (say at 10:00 and 3:00) I would like to have each version saved as `report_1000.txt` and `report_0300.txt`.

```
robocopy \\temp\output c:\users\eric\desktop\robocopy\ report.txt /mon:1 /r:4000
```

Comment: As far as I know, robocopy alone cannot do that. There is no way to change the filenames during operation.